# How to get AST tree from markdown via remark

Tags: javascript, data-structures, markdown, abstract-syntax-tree, remarkjs

using code like this:

```
var remarkAbstract = require("remark");
var remark = remarkAbstract();

let remark = remarkAbstract();
var ast = remark.process(input);
```

but it returns output like:

```
AssertionError: VFile {
  contents: '# header\n\n20 December 2012\n\n![alt](http://yo.io/)\n\ncontent1\n\ncontent2\n\n## header2\n',
  messages: =
```

I'd like to get AST tree [like this](http://remark.js.org/demo/?text=%23%20header%0A20%20December%202012%0A%0A!%5Balt%5D(http%3A%2F%2Fyo.io%2F)%0A%0Acontent1%0A%0Acontent2%0A%23%23%20header2)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By replacing `remark.process(input)` with `remark.parse(input)`.

P.S. Also, this is not a very good question for StackOverflow. I suggest reading up on that :)

Comment: I have the same issue and I've read the docs of `remark`, but the docs seems too simple, not cover how to get ast.

Comment: The Q/A on this question, [How to parse markdown to json using remark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70466143/418950), may help.