# How to parse markdown to json using remark

Tags: node.js, remarkjs

The [remark site](https://remark.js.org/) has a link to an AST explorer for the output of remark - https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/0a92bbf654aca4fdfb3f139254cf0bad/ffe102014c188434c027e43661dbe6ec30042ee2

What I cannot find is how to do the parsing to AST - all the examples convert to HTML.

I have this code

```
import {unified} from 'unified'
import remarkParse from 'remark-parse'
import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm' // git flavoured markdown

const content = `
# My header

This is my content

 - abc
 - def
 
`;

unified()
    .use(remarkParse)
    .use(remarkGfm)
    .process('# Hi\n\n*Hello*, world!')
    .then((file) => {
        console.log(String(file))
    })
```

But I am getting a couple of errors here that I do not know how to get around

```
[remark-gfm] Warning: please upgrade to remark 13 to use this plugin
file:///markdown/node_modules/unified/lib/index.js:520
    throw new TypeError('Cannot `' + name + '` without `Compiler`')
          ^

TypeError: Cannot `process` without `Compiler`
```

Answer (score 6):

You almost have it. Below I've simplified your code, removing unused and unnecessary parts.

```js
import {unified} from 'unified'
import remarkParse from 'remark-parse'

let myResult = unified()
    .use(remarkParse)
    .parse('# Hi\n\n*Hello*, world!');

console.log(JSON.stringify(myResult, null, "   "));
```

According to [ChristianMurphy's GitHub Q/A](https://github.com/unifiedjs/unified/discussions/113#discussioncomment-234473):

> unified.process() will try to take text, turn it into an AST, and back into text.

For your stated purpose, "*...parsing to AST* [JSON]", you don't need or want the "*full-cycle process*" that `unified.process()` is failing to complete, `TypeError: Cannot 'process' without 'Compiler'`. You merely want to parse the input and emit the syntax tree (AST) as JSON. The error here is because `process()`, after parsing your input (markdown string) and turning it into a syntax tree (AST), is then trying to "*compile*" it to some output format. However, you haven't supplied a compiler. But, as I understand your post, you don't need or want to compile the syntax tree into another output (language). So, change from `process()` to `parse()` and emit the resulting syntax tree as JSON.

Comment: I should also note that I removed `remark-gfm` so I don't experience `[remark-gfm] Warning: please upgrade to remark 13 to use this plugin` . `remark-gfm` isn't necessary to accomplish the goal - as I understood it.